# Rollup package axios, can not be used

Tags: node.js, axios, rollup

Axios is used in the project, then packaged using rollup.

On the browser side, it is normal. But the error is reported on the nodejs side.

Error info:

```
node test\test.js
error
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at dispatchXhrRequest (D:\Project\NodeJs\rollup-axios-error-demo\dist\demo.js:684:21)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (D:\Project\NodeJs\rollup-axios-error-demo\dist\demo.js:676:12)
    at dispatchRequest (D:\Project\NodeJs\rollup-axios-error-demo\dist\demo.js:1082:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

I created a demo that will be available for you to view: [rollup-axios-error-demo](https://github.com/BlackHole1/rollup-axios-error-demo)

The code for axios source code to distinguish the running environment is:

```
function getDefaultAdapter() {
  var adapter;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
    // For browsers use XHR adapter
    adapter = require('./adapters/xhr');
  } else if (typeof process !== 'undefined') {
    // For node use HTTP adapter
    adapter = require('./adapters/http');
  }
  return adapter;
}
```

But after packaging, it becomes:

```
function getDefaultAdapter() {
  var adapter;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
    // For browsers use XHR adapter
    adapter = xhr;
  } else if (typeof process !== 'undefined') {
    // For node use HTTP adapter
    adapter = xhr;
  }
  return adapter;
}
```

Caused the XMLHttpRequest to be instantiated on the nodejs side

Comment: Have you found a solution ?...

Comment: No, I wrote a http request code compatible with browser and nodejs.Use require to introduce http and http. To solve the problem of packaging failure

Comment: This problem, even if you change the webpack, it won't work.

Comment: While testing one of dom based utils I faced similar kind of issue. I ended up adding mocks for dom based missing functions. In this case you can mock XMLHttpRequest with https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I had the same problem and resolved it by switching `import axios from 'axios'` to `const axios = require("axios")` in any file where axios was used.

Comment: Now the next rollup issue. ```ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require```

Comment: @oliver dixon Missing an import in your rollup.config i.e. @rollup/plugin-node-resolve?